# How do I rewrite the app's base URL in spring-data-rest links?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, x-forwarded-for

My company uses an API gateway that transforms URLs as follows, modifying both the hostname and the base path of the resource:
`https://apigateway.mycompany.com/myapp/foo -> https://myapp.mycompany.com/foo`

In Spring Data REST, the app wants to generate links using `https://myapp.mycompany.com/foo`. How can I customize the app to force it to produce API gateway links for all `rel` attributes?

I want to change the way that the links are rendered *without* changing the actual paths to those resources on the myapp.mycompany.com server. I checked the docs section on customizing the `rel` but it doesn't appear to cover this use case.

What should I do?

Comment: Try adding `@Import(ForwardedHeaderFilter.class)` on one of your `@Configuration`s.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know the result

Comment: This change solved the issue and allowed me to throw out a maze of junk code! Thanks for your help. Don't forget to post an answer so I can mark it as accepted. We will configure our gateway to send the X-Forwarded-* headers properly if it's not doing that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Spring MVC knows about your load balancer/proxy, it can automatically rewrite generated URLs in Spring Data REST and your own controllers (with `MvcUriComponentsBuilder`) to reflect the original request URL, including scheme, port, and more.

There's a built-in Servlet filter named `ForwardedHeaderFilter` that handles this for you by inspecting well-known forwarding headers such as `X-Forwarded-For`; if you're using Spring Boot, you can set `server.forward-headers-strategy = framework` to get one registered, or you can use `@Import(ForwardedHeaderFilter.class)` to create a bean that Boot will then apply to the container. If you're using Spring MVC without Boot, add this filter to your Servlet configuration.